Unable to Generate a token using Node JS
Requirements:
I am using /v1/token/generate this endpoint to generate a token using userID & roles. But I am unable to fetch the token.
DOCS: https://appbuilder-docs.agora.io/server-side-api/api-reference/token-generate
I followed the above doc, but API is throwing
Response:
Message: The API request is invalid, improperly formed, or missing a required field. Please refer to the API documentation to identify which parameters are valid for your request.
Code: 611
X API KEY: I fetched it from agora console -> create project -> Authentication -> Generate API KEY.
I want to create a channel/meeting. And who so ever have the permission to join the channel/meeting only allowed user can join. (I need to provide the information user can join or not)
I expect a token in response using the same token I want to create a channel/meeting. And at the time of joining agora will automatically validate whether the logged-in user can enter.
